# Text.rich and RichText ignores the spaces when applying backgroundColor

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**Minimum reproducible code:**

```dart
Text.rich(
  TextSpan(
    text: 'Foo',
    children: [
      TextSpan(
        text: '    Bar    ',
        style: TextStyle(
          backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
          color: Colors.white,
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
)
```

[image]

As you can see the spaces to the right of `Bar` were ignored. It started happening with a newer Flutter version. How to fix this issue now?

---

**Note:** I'm not looking for solutions like using a widget in a `WidgetSpan`.

Answer (score 2):

> the spaces to the right of Bar were ignored

no, it's not ignored. but the textStyle not applied.

here when i try applied a background for parent Text. the whitespace is still rendered.

[image]

```
Container(
  color: Colors.amber,
  child: Text.rich(
    TextSpan(
      text: 'Foo',
      children: [
        TextSpan(
          text: '    Bar    ',
          style: TextStyle(
            backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
            color: Colors.white,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ));
```

I think the better way is using `WidgetSpan`

---

but i was thinking that, its only happens with whitespace, how about another [invisble character](https://emptycharacter.com/)?

this what i've tried. using \u200e char

```
TextSpan(
  text: "    Bar    ‎", // in the end of this string, there's \u200e char
  style: TextStyle(
    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
    color: Colors.white,
  ),
),
```

[image]

Comment: By ignore I actually meant the spaces were ignored by the `TextStyle`. Anyway, I like the invisible character workaround, I won't accept it as answer but I'll surely upvote it.

Comment: i just raised the issue on github, hope this gets solved : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/112766

Answer (score 0):

A [punctuation space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2008) or [thin space](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+2009) after the trailing space should do the trick.

```
    TextSpan(
      text: " Bar \u2009", //thin space
      style: TextStyle(
        backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
        color: Colors.white,
      ),
    ),
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cq0lv.png)